# SO account is not deleted one week after it was requested

Tags: support, accounts, deleted-users

[image]

Is it ok?

Comment: It can take extra time based on the amount of things done, as a user who had 18k rep prior to bountying it away, I'd expect it to take additional time for the SE team to process your account. Make sure to check your emails in case you've had any correspondance from them.

Comment: Also, from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account): *"The queue of accounts awaiting deletion is generally processed every Friday, or the previous or next business day if Friday is a holiday. This means that if your account falls into this queue, it could take up to five business days for your deletion request to be processed."* - It's early on Friday in the states at the moment, if it's not done by Monday get in touch with them.

Comment: Thanks for help, I will wait some more time

Comment: @SergeyKurenkov Lamu is correct. The person that normally processes the queue is out this week and I didn't feel comfortable processing the request without their input. It should be processed sometime next week.

Comment: It took 30 days when I deleted my account.

Comment: It's even more upsetting when a Staff member called spell your alias. :'(

Comment: Well, at a quick look the r n does look like an "m"... :-) Actually good that the person read the whole thread and replied!

Comment: even at 200% zoom the gap between the r and n is barely noticeable; whatever font is being used for the comments is perhaps slightly too aggressive with the kerning there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Considering that you have things like an [answer with a score of 277](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25865916/2029983), then I doubt your account will go straight to the delete queue. From [Why do I have a reputation change on my reputation page that says 'User was removed'?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/user-was-removed):

> We have a system in place that examines the impact of removing a
>   user's votes. If the user has cast a large number of votes, deletion
>   will be held up so staff may consider preserving the votes prior to
>   the deletion. The decision is at the staff's discretion and cannot be
>   reversed after the deletion has taken place.

Considering this, and that you have cast 6,938 votes (according to your [profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/184968/sergey-kurenkov?tab=topactivity)), your deletion will most certainly fall under staff review. Deleting your account would have a huge impact, and so I wouldn't be surprised if the staff are making arrangements to retain your votes, etc.